# JQuery Selectize - Uncaught TypeError: $(…).selectize is not a function

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

(I have checked other solutions I found for different questions and they haven't helped me.)

I am attempting to use Selectize.js in my UI and keep getting this error: **$(…).selectize is not a function**.

I am coding in VS using asp.net core with razor pages, so my html is a combination of html and C#. I am also using a typical MVVM/MVC style framework.

**HTML**

```
<!--JQuery version 3.5.1-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/selectize/dist/css/selectize.bootstrap4.css" />

@{
    var groups = ViewData["Groups"] as ArrayList;
}

    <div class="group-select-container" id="group-select-container" hidden>
        <label for="group-select">View data from: </label>

        @{ if (groups.Count > 0)
            {
                <select name="group-select" id="group-select" placeholder="Select a group...">
                    @{
                        foreach (var group in groups)
                        {
                            <option value="@group" id="@group">@group</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#group-select').selectize({
        sortField: {
            field: 'text',
            direction: 'asc'
        },
    });
});
```

I have all micro plugins since I am using the standalone js file.

I have my function wrapped in another function - which I read I am supposed to do.

I am lost to identify the cause for my error. If anyone knows please let me in the know.

Thank you!

Comment: Make a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML - but first look in the network tab to see if it actually is found

Comment: I just created a new project, loaded my scripts under lib folder in wwwroot, set up my html (hardcoded options though) and js the same and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered for whatever reason in asp.net core the default layout.cshtml file includes JQuery at the bottom of the page, overriding my script tag at the top of the page referencing my JS. Removed that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but what if

```
  <select name="group-select" id="group-select" placeholder="Select a group...">
```

wasn't initialized by when you tried using the jQuery selector, perhaps because `groups.Count` wasn't greater than 0 (I'm assuming that's what the `@{ if (groups.Count > 0)` does?
Try outputting the element to check if it's null before calling $(...).selectize and see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried with a hardcoded set options with nothing dynamic coming after. Still nothing.